# Use Session in Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Is it possible to use sessions in eloquent model

```
class StructureModel extends Eloquent {


  protected $table = 'page';        


  protected $attributes = array('lng' => Session::get("lngFunction")); 
}
```

Any help?

Comment: I'm not sure, never tried it. But if it doesn't work you can always pass session values as parameters to your model instance (like `$model->some_value = Session::get("lngFunction");`).

Comment: Hard-coding parameters like these are not recommended.  As Andre recommended, it's best to pass these to the model on a case-by-case basis.  If you hardcode the session and change it's name later, you're going to regret the back-tracking you have to do to solve your problem.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Laravel thing, you simple cannot define variables this way in PHP, this is not how PHP works, but you use the construct method:

```
class StructureModel extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'page';        

    protected $attributes = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();

         $this->attributes = array('lng' => Session::get("lngFunction"));
    }
}
```